# Criar opções dentro de uma classe em Java

Tags: java

Em um jogo onde eu tenha que criar uma classe professor, e dentro a criação de cada professor com a especificação da matéria, pois cada um terá uma ação diferente.

Exemplo:
Professor de matemática (dobra os pontos).
Professor de português (aumenta a força).
Professor de geografia (zera os pontos).

Como eu deveria fazer a criação de cada tipo de professor dentro da classe? Não preciso do código, apenas de uma ideia de como diferenciar os tipos de cada professor. Obrigado

Comment: *"Não preciso do código, apenas de uma ideia de como diferenciar os tipos de cada professor"* entendo que seja um modelo mas, não tem nada que tenha feito para por na pergunta? poderia criar uma classe base "Professor", com associação para para "Materia" e fazer as outras classes específicas herdar de Professor, como "ProfessorMatematica"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você poderia criar um "tipo" na classe professor onde seria um enum e lá colocar uma lógica onde receberia uma interface caracteristica com sua especialidades.
Vou postar um exemplo de código que fica mais fácil de entender.

```
public class Professor {

TipoProfessor tipo;


    public TipoProfessor getTipo() {
       return tipo;
    }

}
```

Tipo

```
public enum TipoProfessor {

MATEMATICA(new DobrarPontos()), HISTORIA(new ZerarPontos()), GEOGRAFIA(new AumentarPoder());

private Caracteristica caracteristica;

private TipoProfessor(Caracteristica caracteristica) {
    this.caracteristica = caracteristica;
}

public Caracteristica getCaracteristica() {
    return caracteristica;
}
```

}

Interface caracteristica

```
public interface Caracteristica {

void getCaracteristica();
```

}

Especialidades

```
public class AumentarPoder implements Caracteristica {

@Override
public void getCaracteristica() {
    System.out.println("Aumentar força");
}
```

}

```
public class DobrarPontos implements Caracteristica {

@Override
public void getCaracteristica() {
    System.out.println("Dobrar pontos");
    
}
```

}

```
public class ZerarPontos implements Caracteristica {

@Override
public void getCaracteristica() {
    System.out.println("Zerar pontos");
}
```

}

Basicamente a ideia é essa, só tem que pensar em um nomes de dominio que façam mais sentido pra você.